# is there any way to convert the .xlsx(excel) format table to .org(emacs) format table?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

we can convert a xlsx table to a csv table then to .org table, if the table like this:

```
|row1|
|row2|
 ....
```

there's no merged cell in the table.
But if the table in xlsx like this:

```
|       col1         |
|--------------------|
|col1.1   |col1.2    |
```

some cell merge information will be lost.

how to convert it to emacs table without lost the information?

Answer (score 1):

Org mode doesn't directly support merged cells, and neither does .csv, so you're stuck on both sides of the conversion.

You could use table.el for merged cells in emacs, but you will still need to convert differently from excel.

References:

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7299/multicolumn-cells-in-org-mode-tables
https://superuser.com/questions/940464/csv-input-for-merged-columns-in-microsoft-excel